# Visual Studio 2015 ツールチップ(summary)の日本語化

Tags: c#

職場で使用しているVisual Studio 2015のツールチップが英語表記なので、これを日本語にするためにランゲージパック等を試してみたのですが、これはメニューの日本語化に必要なファイルをインストールするだけのようで変化がありません。
もう少し調べた結果「VS2015では日本語対応していない」といった回答が見つかりました。
本当に出来ないのでしょうか？
何か回避策があれば教えて下さい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この辺っすね。
VS2015 の .NET FrameWork 4.5 対象のインテリセンスだけ、
誤って英語版の [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) ファイルが格納されている。
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/netframework/ja-JP/83e92fa3-a96d-4672-b9a6-c9bef55e2674/visual-studio-2015-express-for-windows-desktop-vb?forum=vbgeneralja

FrameWork 4.0 とか 4.5.1 とかを選べば日本語が出るそうです。